# Pillow Image.convert TypeError: argument 1 must be str, not int

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to run a model from this [repo](https://github.com/HzFu/DENet_GlaucomaScreen/blob/master/Demo_DENet_GlaucomaScreen.py). and getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "denet_glaucoma_screen/Demo_DENet_GlaucomaScreen.py", line 72, in <module>
    org_img = np.array(Image.fromarray(org_img).resize((2048, int(org_img.shape[1] * img_scale))).convert(3))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 975, in convert
    im = self.im.convert(mode, dither)
TypeError: argument 1 must be str, not int
```

I believe the part that gives the error is this:

```
    for lineIdx, file_test in enumerate(file_test_list):
        temp_txt = [elt.strip() for elt in file_test.split(',')]
        org_img = np.asarray(image.load_img(os.path.join(data_img_path, 
    temp_txt[0])))

    img_scale = 2048.0 / org_img.shape[0]
    org_img = np.array(Image.fromarray(org_img).resize((2048, int(org_img.shape[1] * img_scale))).convert(3))
```

Looking at [Image.convert](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/reference/Image.html) I can't figure out why there would be `3` over there

I tried to change the `3` to `"3"`, `"RGB"`, and even take the entire `convert` off, but I got various errors like `unable to process that type of data` or something similar.

- Update 1:

I tried changing the line:
`org_img = np.array(Image.fromarray(org_img).resize((2048, int(org_img.shape[1] * img_scale))).convert(3))`
to
`org_img = np.array(Image.fromarray(org_img).resize((2048, int(org_img.shape[1] *img_scale), 3)))`
But I got the following error:

```
   File "denet_glaucoma_screen/Demo_DENet_GlaucomaScreen.py", line 74, in <module>
    img_scale), 3)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1745, in resize
    return self._new(self.im.resize(size, resample, box))
TypeError: argument 1 must be sequence of length 2, not 3
```

- Update 2:
  Tried changing the above to:
  `org_img = np.array(Image.fromarray(org_img).resize((2048, int(org_img.shape[1] * img_scale), 3)), mode='RGB')`
  But I got the following error:

```
  File "denet_glaucoma_screen/Demo_DENet_GlaucomaScreen.py", line 74, in <module>
    img_scale), 3)), mode='RGB')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1745, in resize
    return self._new(self.im.resize(size, resample, box))
TypeError: argument 1 must be sequence of length 2, not 3
```

- Update 3:
  Tried running:

```
org_img = np.array(Image.fromarray(org_img, mode='RGB').resize((2048, int(org_img.shape[1]*img_scale), 3)))
```

But I got the following error:

```
  File "denet_glaucoma_screen/Demo_DENet_GlaucomaScreen.py", line 73, in <module>
    org_img = np.array(Image.fromarray(org_img, mode='RGB').resize((2048, int(org_img.shape[1]*img_scale), 3)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1745, in resize
    return self._new(self.im.resize(size, resample, box))
TypeError: argument 1 must be sequence of length 2, not 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed the code from the original repo incorrectly. This is what they have for `org_img`:

```
org_img = scipy.misc.imresize(org_img, (2048, int(org_img.shape[1]*img_scale), 3))
```

The `imresize` from `scipy` is since depreciated. If you look at the code and docs for the old `scipy` function, you can see that they are passing `org_img` for the array and `(2048, int(org_img.shape[1]*img_scale), 3)` for the size- i.e. that 3 is part of the tuple specifying the resize- they are not using it as a `mode` for convert as you are trying to do in your code.

Since this is in 3D, per the 3 dimensions on the resize, the `scipy` docs say:

> For 3-D and 4-D arrays, mode will be set to 'RGB' and 'RGBA' respectively.

So you want:

```
numpy.array(Image.fromarray(org_img, mode='RGB').resize((2048, int(org_img.shape[1]*img_scale))))
```

Comment: @new_one can you try it with `mode='RGB` - see my updated answer

Comment: I did! Please see my update. Again, thank you so much for your time!!

Comment: @new_one no problem! can you try calling `mode='RGB` in the `Image.fromarray()` function? I updated for that. I can't find in the documents whether or not the resize from pillow will accept 3D resizing... it seems like it should

Comment: @new_one okay so the `.resize` can only resize 2 dimensions I guess. Just take out the three entirely and see if the `mode = 'RGB'` gets ride of the unable to process that type of data error that you got when you originally tried to cut the three

Comment: Yesssss!!!! It ran. Took the 3 out and the RGB took care of the rest. You're the best.